# Variables in my simple jQuery slider are not working as expected. Could anyone take a look?

Tags: jquery, timer, slider

So, I had need of a very, very simple image slider. Instead of wrestling with a far too capable plugin, I thought I'd just write one.

I've put it into a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/magnakai/7FUBB/)

There is a container div 620px wide, and the internal div is 1240px wide. Thus only half of it is in view at any one time, and I just animate the left attribute of the internal div. Foo moves it to the first slide, and Bar Humbug moves it to the second one. This works fine.

So, I was asked to add a timer in. So, every five seconds it should go to the other slide, whichever that one is. If you move to the other slide manually, it waits a bit longer before moving by itself again. Being a general programming n00b, I tried to do this with `if`s and variables, which seemed to make sense to me.

However, something in here doesn't work. It happily moves to the second slide, but will never move back by itself. I'm assuming this is something to do with the variables not being read within the various functions, but they do get changed, and the console.logs do report the correct number. So perhaps the `if`s aren't reading the variables. Frankly, I'm a little lost as to where to move from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I've added the code below incase the fiddle doesn't work for someone, or incase you prefer to have it inline here.

Here's the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var speed = 5000;
    var timerOn = 0;
    var slideNumber = 1;
    console.log(slideNumber)

    function slideTimer() 
    { 

        if (timerOn = 1) {

            if (slideNumber=1) {
                goToSlide2();
                console.log(slideNumber)
            }

            else if (slideNumber=2) {
                goToSlide1();
                console.log(slideNumber)
            }

        };

    }

    function goToSlide2()
    {
        $('#slider_arrow').animate({left: '375px'}, 400);
        $('#slider_content').animate({left: '-620px'}, 400, function(){
            slideNumber=2;
            window.setTimeout(function()
            {
                timerOn = 1;
            }, speed);
        });
    }

    function goToSlide1()
    {
        $('#slider_arrow').animate({left: '75px'}, 400);
        $('#slider_content').animate({left: '0px'}, 400, function(){
            slideNumber=1;
            window.setTimeout(function()
            {
                timerOn = 1;
            }, speed);
        });
    }    


    $('#isr_title span.slider_button.foo').click(function() {
        timerOn = 0;
        goToSlide1();
    });

    $('#isr_title span.slider_button.bar_humbug').click(function() {
        timerOn = 0;
        goToSlide2();
    });

    window.setInterval(
        function()
        {
        slideTimer();
        }, 4000);


});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="main" role="main" class="clearfix">
    <div id="branding_section_buttons">
        <h1 id="isr_title"><span class="slider_button foo">Foo</span> <span class="slider_button bar_humbug"> Bar Humbug</span></h1>
        <div id="slider_arrow" class="target_independent">
        </div>
    </div> 

<div id="slider">
                <div id="slider_content" class="clearfix">
                    <p>Our <span class="highlight">lorem</span> ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span class="highlight">lorem</span> ipsum <span class="highlight">lorem</span> ipsum.</p>
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/280/200" alt="" width="280" height="200">
                    <p style="color: red;">Our <span class="highlight">lorem</span> ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum <span class="highlight">lorem</span> ipsum <span class="highlight">lorem</span> ipsum.</p>
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/280/200" alt="" width="280" height="200">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Here's the relevant CSS

```
#slider
{
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 200px;
}

#slider_content
{
    width: 1240px;
    position: absolute;

}

#slider_content p, #slider_content img
{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#slider_content p
{
    font-size:182%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#slider_content p span.highlight
{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #445daa;
}

#slider_content img
{
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#slider_content
{
    width: 1240px;
    position: absolute;

}

#slider_content p, #slider_content img
{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
}

#slider_content p
{
    font-size:182%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#slider_content p span.highlight
{
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #445daa;
}

#slider_content img
{
    margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI: a single equal sign is for assigning a value (e.g. var foo = bar).

For logical tests you use if(foo == bar).

Because you're putting assignments if your "if" statements, they're always returning true.

Comment: I should also mention, for the sake of completeness, that you could also use the strict equality operator "if(foo === bar)". Strict equality matches value AND type. so ('2' == 2) returns true, but ('2' === 2) returns false, because you're comparing a string and an integer.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, especially for the pointer on strict equality operators. I hadn't come across those before and I can see how they'd be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your variable declarations up top, start out with timerOn = 1, then change all of your if statements to use double equal signs instead of singles.

That seemed to work on the fiddle.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice the if statements.

Comment: Amazing, thank you so very much! I don't know how I managed to miss the correct syntax in my googling. Gold stars all round!

Answer (score 0):

Off a quick look, I would say your problem is that variable which aren't global in scope are being accessed in functions. For example, the slideNumber variable is actually local to the function you are passing to $(document).ready(); You need those variables declared outside of the scope of that function to be accessible elsewhere.

Additionally, you don't want to define your functions inside the $(document).ready() function. See my revised version below.

```
var speed = 5000;
var timerOn = 0;
var slideNumber = 1;

function slideTimer() 
    { 

        if (timerOn = 1) {

            if (slideNumber=1) {
                goToSlide2();
                console.log(slideNumber)
            }

            else if (slideNumber=2) {
                goToSlide1();
                console.log(slideNumber)
            }

        };

    }

    function goToSlide2()
    {
        $('#slider_arrow').animate({left: '375px'}, 400);
        $('#slider_content').animate({left: '-620px'}, 400, function(){
            slideNumber=2;
            window.setTimeout(function()
            {
                timerOn = 1;
            }, speed);
        });
    }

    function goToSlide1()
    {
        $('#slider_arrow').animate({left: '75px'}, 400);
        $('#slider_content').animate({left: '0px'}, 400, function(){
            slideNumber=1;
            window.setTimeout(function()
            {
                timerOn = 1;
            }, speed);
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(slideNumber);

    $('#isr_title span.slider_button.foo').click(function() {
        timerOn = 0;
        goToSlide1();
    });

    $('#isr_title span.slider_button.bar_humbug').click(function() {
        timerOn = 0;
        goToSlide2();
    });

    window.setInterval(
        function()
        {
        slideTimer();
        }, 4000);


});
```

Comment: The named functions are within the same closure as his variables, so scope isn't the issue. The variables are accessible to everything he's written.

Comment: I'd swear I've had issues with declaring variables that way before. Maybe it was browser specific, maybe I just remember wrongly!

Comment: You're absolutely right that the variables aren't global when they're declared within the scope of $(document).ready(). The reason is worked is because he defined those named functions within the same scope. If they had been declared outside of ready() closure (as most people tend to do), they wouldn't have access to variables which had been declared inside.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is what I'm doing bad practice? Is it better to stick the functions and variables outside of ready()? Or does it make no difference, as long as I don't try and access them in a different scope?

Comment: I think it depends on the application. If you don't need to access them outside of that ready() closure, then they're probably better off staying where they are. That way, you're not polluting the global namespace.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I still get taken aback by how coldly and unabashedly logical programming is. Thank you for all your help.